# NIS domain broadcast message

Tags: broadcast

Is there a broadcast message utility for NIS domain users?

Answer (score 2):

Not standard, no.  You could write a daemon to run on NIS clients that periodically polled a custom map and fed messages therein to whatever notification mechanism exists (DBus, etc.).